# Knex.js Where Clause contains mandatory AND and Optional OR - SQL

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, query-builder, knex.js

I'm having a SQLite database table of Employees

Table Name: **Employee**

```
ID    Name    Country   CountyID   Status
1     John    IN        1          Active
2     Jack    US        1          InActive
3     Emma    UK        1          Active
4     Josh    US        1          Active
5     Jill    US        0          Active
```

I need to fetch '`Active`' person whose are residing in '`IN`' and '`US`' OR CountyID '`1`'.

Sample Code:

```
const dbContext = require("knex")({
        client: "sqlite3",
        connection: {
            filename: filename.db
        },
        useNullAsDefault: true
});

const persons = dbContext('Employee').where({Status: 'Active'}). ???
```

SQL Query is

```
SELECT * FROM Employee WHERE Status = 'Active' AND (Country IN ('IN', 'US') OR CountyID = 1)
```

I required the equivalent Knex Query. Kindly assist me in this regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somethin like this should do it:

```
dbContext('Employee').where('Status', 'Active').where(builder => {
  builder.whereIn('Country', ['IN', 'US']).orWhere('CountyID', 1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks. Let me know whats the difference between `.where` and `.andwhere` ?

Comment: they are aliases... no difference at all.